# How to convert EPOCH time in String to Timestamp in Ignite by SQL

Tags: ignite

I have to convert a varchar column in Ignite table containing EPOCH
time to Timestamp.

I tried but could not find any available date function.

Epoch time example in table : "20210428060207"

Is there any way to achive with SQL query in Ignite?.

Actual Problem: I have to extract hour, day and month from this epoch time.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to leverage the `DATEADD` [function](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/date-time-functions#dateadd) to transform a `Long`-represented value into a `TIMESTAMP` along with the `EXTRACT` [function](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/date-time-functions#extract) to grab required parts from the produced `TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT 
   EXTRACT (HOUR FROM DATEADD('MILLISECOND', EPOCH_FIELD, DATE '1970-01-01')) AS HOUR,
   EXTRACT (DAY FROM DATEADD('MILLISECOND', EPOCH_FIELD, DATE '1970-01-01')) AS DAY,
   EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATEADD('MILLISECOND', EPOCH_FIELD, DATE '1970-01-01')) AS MONTH
FROM "schema_name".TABLE_NAME;
```

Another option is to utilize *Ignite* [custom](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/custom-sql-func) *SQL* functions. It's possible to put conversion logic there. In that case *SQL* call would be simpler (`FOO` is a custom function here).

```
SELECT FOO(EPOCH_FIELD) FROM "schema_name".TABLE_NAME;
```